# Showing a button only in edit mode Oracle Apex 5

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I want to add a button in the Oracle Apex Form which should only be shown when the form is opened in the edit mode and not in the create mode.

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition on your button based on whatever defines your application to be in "edit" mode.

I recommend you be as declarative as possible
http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2013/05/performance-of-apex-conditions.html

Answer (score 0):

The solution

1- Click the button

2- Go to server-side condition

3- Select the Type Item is NOT NULL

4- Select your primary key item

5- SAVE changes

because in CREATE MODE still your primary key value not created but in EDIT mode primary key created and you need to EDIT.